# jquery mouseenter mouseout in menu

Tags: jquery, mouseout, mouseenter

I met some jquery menu mouseenter problem. How to fix when mouse enter `p`, the `p` still `display block`?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').mouseenter(function(){
        $('p').css('display','none');
        $(this).next('p').slideDown('slow');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('p').slideUp('slow');
    });
    $('p').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css('display','block');
    });​
});
</script>
<div>
    <a>menu1</a>
    <p>about us</p>
    <a>menu2</a>
    <p>contact</p>
</div>
<style>
div{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0; 
    width:600px;
    height:20px;    
}
p{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}​
</style>
​
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KTvf7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it for ya..

```
  $('a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('p').css('display','none');
    $(this).next('p').slideDown('slow');});
$('p').mouseleave(function(){
    $('p').slideUp('slow');
});
$('p').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: (1) `$('p').mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css('display','block'); $(this).show(); });` doesn't do anything (`p` is alreay block and is visible otherwise you can't enter it). (2) if the user leaves the menu from an `a` element the `p` still shows.

Comment: I will agree with you...My mistake of rushing.. $(this).show(); is useless in the above code

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `<ul>`? I think it's better for what you're trying to do.

**html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu One</a>
        <p>About Us</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Two</a>
        <p>Contact Us</p>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
li { float: left; padding: 0 2em; }
p {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0 2em;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**jQ:**

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('p').stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('p').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

**Example**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/KTvf7/7/)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to structure your menu otherwise, like:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>item
            <ul>
                <li>sub item</li>
                <li>sub item</li>
                <li>sub item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And add `.menu li ul { display: none; }` to the css.

In this structure, entering and leaving the `.menu > li` works great.

---

If you still want to stick to your structure, you can only attach `mouseleave` to the container. I gave it a class `.menu` in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/KTvf7/4/):

```
$('.menu a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.menu p').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).next('p').slideDown('slow');
})

$('.menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $('p', this).slideUp('slow');
});
```